# Regex Table Lookup not working with Click Element variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a regex lookup table variable to output text based on the Click Element containing a specific string. However, the variable appears as null despite the string definitely being in the Click Element. Can anyone help?

[Here is my regex lookup table variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHPm9.jpg)
[Here is the debug window showing null (the Action field is where the regex table variable should populate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9OfY.jpg)

[Here is the full tag that contains the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dgaW.jpg)

[Here is the trigger for the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0jqN.jpg)
I have tried various different strings from the Click Element, without luck.

The trigger for the tag is based on the same string, and the trigger works, which only adds to my confusion.

I feel like the problem must be obvious, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this as well until I realized that "Click Element" is actually an object, not a string. It's based on `gtm.element` in the `datalayer`.

So, in order to do this you'll need to create a custom datalayer variable that more accurately targets a specific child key.

To see what I mean, open a link in a new tab and then type in `datalayer` into your browser console, and press enter. You'll see something like:

```
3: 
event: "gtm.click"
gtm.element: a#mylinkclass.my-class.something.else
accessKey: ""
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
etc....
```

[Screenshot of chrome inspector console showing datalayer children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddRX9.png)

So, then you'll have to create custom variable to target the key you'd like. For example, a datalayer variable that you create with `gtm.element.className` would return `my-class something else` for link `<a href="/my-link-here/" class="my-class something else" id="mylinkclass">Link Text</a>`.

Using this method I was able to create a Regex lookup table just like you're trying to do.

Here's a post that goes into some more detail on some of the above:

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/click-element-variable-in-google-tag-manager/

Comment: I accepted this as the correct answer, but I realized just now I never thanked you. So, THANK YOU!!!! You were very helpful. @nocabt

Comment: No problem glad I could help!